# asp.net: How do I combine two models together to be able to create a Parent and all of its child entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to use ASP.net and MVC and in need of some help.I am currently working on a project which is an online recipe book, and I have various tables but the two tables I want to combine into one view is Recipe and RecipeIngredients, as shown below:

**Recipe.cs**

```
    namespace TheOnlineFoodBook.Models
    {
        public class Recipe
        {
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int RecipeID { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Recipe")]
            public string RecipeName { get; set; }
            [Display(Name= "Cuisine")]
            public int CuisineID { get; set; }
            public string Directions { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Preperation Time:")]
            public double PreperationTime { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Cooking Time:")]
            public double CookingTime { get; set; }


            public virtual List<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("CuisineID")]
            public virtual Cuisine Cuisine { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**RecipeIngredient.cs**

```
    public class RecipeIngredient
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public int IngredientID { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public int MeasurementID { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
        public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've read a little about combining models to create a viewModel but i'm not sure how I would go about doing this, and I also want to be able to add multiple RecipeIngredients entries at the same time when creating a Recipe. Currently I have the basic CRUD views working which entity framework created for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do what you need?

```
public class RecipeViewModel
{
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeIngredients> RecipeIngredientsList { get; set; }
}
```

You won't be able to use data annotations as effectively, but if that isn't a concern you will now be able to attach multiple `RecipeIngredients` to the same `Recipe` for your page.

Comment: I have created a view model like that i'm just not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You can load your ViewModel like you would any other class, and then pass that model to your view. `return View(model);` In your view you can access each of the properties like any other class. `Model.Recipe.RecipeName` and `Model.RecipeIngredientsList[i].Notes`

Answer (score 1):

You already have a "Recipe" object in "RecipeIngredient" so using "RecipeIngredient" as model in your view would give you access to "Recipe" properties, another approach you could take is using `@modelTuple<Recipe,RecipeIngredient>` in your view after passing `new Tuple<Person, Order>(new Recipe(),new RecipeIngredient());` as you would pass a model, but I wouldn't see the use in following the later one since "RecipeIngredient" already has "Recipe"